# Identifying polygons types based on line segments

Tags: qgis, polygon, field-calculator, line

I want to identify several types of polygons. I got stuck at two types of categories that I don't know how to identify. I will post every situation here, maybe someone has an idea.

I have a layer with polygon segments (line type) which has a calculated field where the front street is equal to 1 and the others to 0. I also have the field with the number of faces.

I have to identify on this layer with line segments that also have the group field with identifier for each polygon. Then it's easy for me to turn this layer back into a polygon layer, but I don't know how to identify 2 types of plots.

*Case 1*: angle plots - at the crossroads of two roads.

[image]

Here i have to identify the consecutive segments that have the value 1 in the `"front street"` field.

*Case 2*: polygons with 4 sides, which has two sides overlooking two different roads.

[image]

Here i have to find the polygons that have 2 parallel street segments.

Comment: How is your data structured: can you provide sample data and/or a screenshot of your attribute table? Why do you want to do this with lines? Why don't you use the polygon layer for this task?

Answer (score 7):

Prepare your data: Make sure the polygon layer contains a uniqe identifyer attribute called `id`. Do **not** use the `fid` field if working with Geopackage: after step 2, this field will not be unique any more and you can't save it as Geopackage.

1. Convert the polygons to lines.
2. Explode lines
3. Create a new attribute field namend `bound` with field calculator to identify each line segment (polygon side): `inner` if it borders to a neighboring polygon, `outer` if not. Use this expression: `if (overlay_contains( @layer),'inner','outer')` ([`overlay_contains`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html?highlight=overlay_contains#overlay-contains) is available since QGIS 3.16).

   *Screenshot: see the exploded lines labeled with the output (black); blue labels represent the `id` of each polygon:*
   [image]
4. In step 3, we calculated for each line segment (each side of the polygon) if it borders on another polygon (`inner`) or not (`outer`). Now let's create another value: each side of the polygon is connected to two other sides (lines) **of the same polygon** (at start- and end-points: the corners of the polygon). So now let's calculate for each line/side how many of the two connected lines/sides are `outer`, too. Create a new field `neighboring_outer`, using this expression in the field calculator:

```
array_length(
    array_remove_all( 
         array_foreach (
            array_filter (
                overlay_touches( 
                    @layer,
                    $id
                ),
                attribute (
                    get_feature_by_id(
                        @layer,
                        @element 
                    ),
                    'id'
                ) = id
            ),
            if (
                attribute (
                    get_feature_by_id(
                        @layer, 
                        @element
                    ),
                    'bound'
                ) = 'outer',
                @element,
                0
            )
        ),
        0
    )
)
```

*Screenshot showing the result by labeling each line with the value calculated: the number of neighboring line with `outer` values each line has:*
[image]

5. The distribution of these values now can be used to differentiate between different categories of polygons, based on two characteristics:

- 1. sum of `'outer'` sides per polygon (how many sides of the polygon are `'outer'`)
- 2. highest value per polygon of `'outer'` values for neighboring sides (`neighboring_outer`)

Thus calculate a new field `cat_code` with this expression:

```
aggregate( 
    @layer, 
    'sum', 
    neighboring_outer, 
    filter:= attribute (@parent, 'id') = id
) ||
aggregate( 
    @layer, 
    'max', 
    neighboring_outer, 
    filter:= attribute ( @parent, 'id') = id
)
```

*Screenshot: the blue labels are the result of the calculation. The value of the blue label is simply a concatenation of the `sum of black values per polygon` with the `highest black value per polygon` (black values as above):*
[image]

6. Copy the created `cat_code` from the exploded line- back to the original polygon layer. Create there a field, called `cat_code` as well using this expression:

```
attribute (
    get_feature (
        'exploded',
        'id',
        id
    ),
    'cat_code'
)
```

7. We have 6 different cases, coded with these numbers: 0, 21, 41, 42, 62, 82 (the higher the number, the more outside sides the polygon has). We can convert these numbers to a descriptive text, creating a new field `category` with this expression:

```
case 
   when "cat_code" = 0 then 'enclosed'
   when "cat_code" = 21 then 'inside'
   when "cat_code" = 41 then 'corner'
   when "cat_code" = 42 then 'front/back'
   when "cat_code" = 62 then 'exposed'
   when "cat_code" = 82 then 'isolated'
end
```

And this is how the result looks like:

[image]

---

You might remark a problem with polygons no. 16, 17 and 18 (see next screenshot below for identification): here, the results are wrong (see last two screenshots above). That's because in this case, the southern side of polygon 16 borders on two different polygons. For polygon 16, we have one straight line, northern line of polygon 17 and 18 are shorter lines. Because of that, in step 3, these lines are not recognized by `overlay_contains()` as being contained in each other (16 is not contained in 17 nor in 18; 17 and 18 are not contained in 16).

In this case, the problem can easily be avoided by adding a vertex in the polygon on the southern line of polygon 16 where it meets the corners of polygons 17 and 18.

*Screenshot with additional vertex (red arrow) that affects the results for polygons 16 to 18 that are now correctly categorized:*
[image]

Comment: This method is superb. However, this require quite "clean" polygons". 
In my case I have worst polygons since they have a higher number of sides, even if quite small.
The result for your step 3 is this:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSYeG.png

I tried to simplify the geometry with no great success since when the simplification occurs it may affect the boundary of the line (goes from inner to outer for instance in contiguous buildings) 
I am still trying to understand what to do.... any clue would be great

Comment: For more complex forms, you might indeed need another solution. Maybe some of the steps here can provide some ideas.

Comment: Maybe a Minimum Oriented Rectangle could help you? It will for sure generate a simplified version of your geometries - however, topology will not be preserved.

Comment: Looks good, but Minimum Oriented Rectangle originates not coincident inner lines and then wrong outer faces

Comment: I believe that could be something related with both "outer " inner"  line condition and the orientation. Some type of sumif and then a geometry logic. Still trying...