# Adding attribute of polygon orientation depending on neighbors in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, attribute-table, fields-attributes, boundaries

I have a shapefile with buildings as polygons. Is it possible to add attribute columns referring if the polygon boundary is "other polygon" or "outdoors" for a certain orientation (south for example)?

For instance:
[image]

These buildings would have as attribute "South orientation" = outdoors - since they don't have any building contiguous to them.

Whereas, these ones:
[image]

Would have "South orientation" = "building" since they have building contiguous (not the bottom one)

Final result should be something as (1 - contiguous building, 0 - outdoors):
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "certain orientation"?

Comment: I mean façade orientation. So a square building as 4 for example.   I would like to know for a large set of buildings, for each one of them if the south orientated façade is contiguous or not (so facing outdoors)

Comment: But on the below image, it could also be "North orientation" = "building", is not it? Do you have an attribute that describes the facade orientation? What you can do is to count neighbor buildings.

Comment: yes, exactly!. I was only referring to the south orientation in the example. No, I don't have the orientation attribute

Comment: So, it should always point to South, is not it?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I would like to do it for all orientations (lets consider just 4: N,S,W,E). I was asking for just one and then replicate for others

Comment: Maybe centroid - wedge buffers - join attributes by location

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/397373/88814

Comment: Something similar to gis.stackexchange.com/a/397373/88814  I would personally look at the solution in a different way and would create some linear data structures called 'common_wall' and 'external_wall' from the polygons and then join them via relational joins (or spatial topology if you are really keen). The idea of neat 'South_boundary/north_boundary' attribute values is a bit messy.