# Detect and calculate the length of exposed edges of building polygons

Tags: qgis

I would like to calculate the compactness ratio of buildings, which is: **Surface area of the building envelope (exposed to the exterior) /  Volume of the building**

To define the surface area (exposed) of the envelope, I must only include the edges of the polygons which are not overlapping with the next building (this where heat losses occur).
Please find an example below:

[image]

I have found the "overlap analysis" in QGIS, but it works only between two different layers and seems to concern the whole polygon rather than only edges... Exploding each polygon can become quite messy and I wonder if there any tool which could do this.

Comment: Interesting question! It may be that exploding the polygons are less messy than you think. It might be possible to make a not to complicated script doing this. How is your data stored? (Shapefile, postgis ... ? ) and is it polygons or multipolygons? Would it be possible to upload the dataset (or some similiar data) somewhere?

Comment: Maybe this can help or at least give an idea: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/397373/88814

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the steps you need to follow to get your results:

1. Dissolve the buildings so all overlapping lines are gone.
2. Use the **Boundary** tool to extract all edges of the buildings.
3. Use the **Explode lines** tool to make single segments of the lines.

There you have all the surface area that is not covered by the buildings.
If you want to see which edge is for which building follow these additional steps:

4. buffer the undissolved buildings by 0.1 meters. DO NOT DISSOLVE THE BUFFER!
5. Use the **Join attributes by location** tool. Put the lines as *Base layer* and the buffered building for the join layer. Use the *within* option instead of *intersects*

There you have it. Lines with the information of the buildings.

Comment: Thank you! This works very well - although for (5) it should be "within" and not "contain".

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Md01 ! I mixed it with python options :)

Answer (score 1):

A bit convoluted but:

Create a virtual layer to find the unexposed sides:

```
select st_intersection(a.geometry, b.geometry)
from parcels a
join parcels b
on st_intersects(a.geometry, b.geometry)
where a.fid <> b.fid
```

Boundary tool to turn all polygons into lines

Difference of boundaries and virtual layer

[image]