# Counting adjacent polygons using QGIS

Tags: qgis, count, adjacency

Is there a way to count adjacent polygons using QGIS?

I want to create a new field with the number of adjacent polygons.

I want to count adjacent polygons to determine if a polygon (house) is a corner house or an inbetween house.

[image]

Comment: See here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/397373/88814

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The suggestion provided by @JGH is good but will only work in some instances, I'd suggest you to use nearest with an upper limit and a safe maximum distance.

In my example below I used `array_length(overlay_nearest( @layer ,"",limit:=10,max_distance:=5))` this assume your projection is in metric units.

Here is a comparison of a few overlay methods and their results:
[image]

Answer (score 12):

Using the field calculator, you can use `array_length( overlay_intersects( @layer,""))` to identify and count the intersecting geometries

[image]